# Microsoft Teams DATE and TIME functions is not showing localized date/time format in adaptive cards on MS Teams desktop

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I have following adaptive card

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Your package will arrive on {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:00:00Z, SHORT)}} at {{TIME(2017-02-14T06:00:00Z)}}",
        "wrap": true
    }
]
}
```

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features

When I run MS Teams on the browser and change the browser language it shows me the date/time in localized format correctly, but when I change my timezone locally the desktop app of MS teams is not showing the date/time in localized formats

Comment: I have tried changing MS teams application language, it doesn't work that way also.

Comment: tracking the thread here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185730/why-does-ms-teams-date-and-time-functions-on-adapt